# checking to see if a vaule is in a particular key of an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, explode

I'm new to working with arrays so I need some help. With getting just one vaule from an array. I have an original array that looks like this:

```
 $array1= Array(   
     [0] => 1_31   
     [1] => 1_65  
     [2] => 29_885...)
```

What I'm trying to do is seach for and return just the value after the underscore. I've figured out how to get that data into a second array and return the vaules as a new array.

```
    foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
    $id = explode('_',$value);
}
```

which gives me:

```
Array ( [0] => 1  [1] => 31 ) 
Array ( [0] => 1  [1] => 65 ) 
Array ( [0] => 29 [1] => 885 )
```

I can also get a list of the id's or part after the underscore by using `$id[1]` I'm just not sure if this is the best way and if it is how to do a search. I've tried using `in_array()` but that searches the whole array and I couldn't make it just search one key of the array.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the part after underscore is unique, make it a key for new array:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
    list($v,$k) = explode('_',$value);
    $newArray[$k] = $v;
}
```

So you can check for key existence with `isset($newArray[$mykey])`, which will be more efficient.

Comment: Yeah that part after the underscore is unique to the array which it's in.

Comment: +1 for thinking outside of the box. Wasn't sure if the "initial overhead" was worth it, or it was only going to be iterated over once.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`preg_grep()`](http://ask.amoeba.co.in/php-search-in-an-array-for-values-matching-a-pattern-regex-wildcard/) to grep an array:

```
$array1= array("1_31", "1_65", "29_885");
$num = 65;
print_r(preg_grep("/^\d+_$num$/", $array1));
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1_65
)
```

See http://ideone.com/3Fgr8

Comment: I have to get rid of the part before the underscore and check against that. the problem is that if `$num = 1` then It would return both 1_31 and 1_65. Where really what I want for `$num = 1` would be 1_1.

Comment: overkill, though still a viable option. (why's everyone so quick to use regex with every "find value in a string" question?)

Comment: @Bandon No, it would return `1_1` (see http://ideone.com/3ykhB). It currently checks the value to the right of the underscore. Do you want it to check the left, right, both?

Comment: @Brad Because he asked for a "better" way and I gave a short alternative? :P

Comment: @Brad The God of this question? ;-)

Comment: Besides, my answer is what I'd likely do if I was coding this up. The accepted answer uses more memory, is no faster and is longer in length.

Comment: @marcog the GODESS of this question more like it :). Your solution seems like a good one but I would still have to break off the part before the underscore.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you're doing it just about as well as anyone else would.

**EDIT**

Alternate method:

```
$array1 = array_map(create_function('$a','$_ = explode("_",$a); return $_[1];'),$array1);
echo in_array(3,$array1) ? "yes" : "no"; // 3 being the example
```

Comment: Thanks,I'll take that as a complement. I'm getting there I just got a bit stuck.

Comment: @BandonRandon: No worries, we all started off somewhere. I would work on (if possible) not having the values be stored in that fashion. Though, if it's not your doing, parsing it is just about as good as it gets.

Comment: The data is coming from an api using JSON. They are bus route numbers and the part before the underscore is the agency and the part after is the route number.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to agree. If you wish to see is a value exists in an array however just use the 'array_key_exists' function, if it returns true use the value for whatever.

Comment: I tried that couldn't get it to work.Of course I was probably doing it wrong. I tried `if(array_key_exists('1', $value))`